# How to troubleshoot errors after successful Drupal update?

Tags: upgrading, debugging

Recently, I updated a Drupal core website from 7.31 to 7.34 and the process was successful, without any error during the upgrade.

It's showing the latest version of 7.34 core in the Status Report, BUT if I visit the home page or any other pages, then it's showing different different errors.

I can access the Administration pages BUT I don't know how to solve these issues.

Here you can see the details about it:

- http://cityguest.norrwing.ro/en
- http://cityguest.norrwing.ro/en/privacy-policy

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask your question in a way that will make it answerable even if content linked will not be available or will no longer show your issue.

Comment: Have you run *update* after the upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I did " run update" after the core upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2378893#comment-9365665) you should re-upload common.inc file in includes folder.

> I don't use Drupal Commons, but I got the same error when upgrading
>   Drupal Crore from 7.20 to 7.34.
>
> This function was added in Drupal Core 7.33 so check your core version
>   is later than that. https://www.drupal.org/node/2369141
>
> I then fixed it by reuploading common.inc in the includes folder. Must
>   have not uploaded correctly the first time.